# Getting an error when installing wifi driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, networking, drivers, 20.04, kernel

```
Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=5.13.0-52-generic.........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-52-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

make.log

```
DKMS make.log for rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 for kernel 5.13.0-52-generic (x86_64)
Thursday 07 July 2022 10:40:58 AM IST
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.13.0-52-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-52-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:35,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/wifi.h:1006: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 1006 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
      |
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:86,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:42,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1657: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 1657 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
      |
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_security.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:35,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_security.c:22:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/wifi.h:1006: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 1006 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
      |
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:86,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:42,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_security.c:22:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1657: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 1657 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
      |
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_debug.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:35,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_debug.c:22:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/wifi.h:1006: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 1006 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
      |
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:86,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:42,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_debug.c:22:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1657: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 1657 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
      |
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_io.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:35,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_io.c:52:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/wifi.h:1006: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 1006 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
      |
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service_linux.h:86,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/osdep_service.h:42,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/core/rtw_io.c:52:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1657: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘isFileReadable’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2087:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_fs’; did you mean ‘get_sa’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 2087 |   oldfs = get_fs();
      |           ^~~~~~
      |           get_sa
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2087:11: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} from type ‘int’
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2088:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘set_fs’; did you mean ‘sget_fc’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 2088 |   set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
      |   ^~~~~~
      |   sget_fc
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2088:10: error: ‘KERNEL_DS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘KERNFS_NS’?
 2088 |   set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
      |          KERNFS_NS
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2088:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘retriveFromFile’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2125:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} from type ‘int’
 2125 |    oldfs = get_fs();
      |            ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2126:11: error: ‘KERNEL_DS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘KERNFS_NS’?
 2126 |    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
      |           KERNFS_NS
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c: In function ‘storeToFile’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2160:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘mm_segment_t’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} from type ‘int’
 2160 |    oldfs = get_fs();
      |            ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.c:2161:11: error: ‘KERNEL_DS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘KERNFS_NS’?
 2161 |    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
      |           KERNFS_NS
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:281: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1879: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-52-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1886: modules] Error 2
                                                                                                                                                                                          419,24        Bot
```

Comment: As per the output, check the log file `/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log` and append it to your question...

Comment: make: *** [Makefile:1887: modules] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

Those errors indicate that the package is too old to compile on your 5.13 kernel version. I suggest that you install this package instead. https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Please carefully consult the README for installation instructions. There is no DKMS process and so the package will need to be recompiled after every kernel update.

Also, despite Mr. Finger's dire warnings about Ubuntu, the package compiles without error or warnings on my 5.15 system.

Comment: Hii , these all commands run successfully , no error shown but wifi symbol not shown in my system , please help me

Comment: How did you determinae that you have an rtl8723de device? Please run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your original question to add the result.